# On passing null to ReplaySubject.next() in my angular application I'm getting an error and I don't understand why. Help is appreciated

Tags: angular

```
private currentUserSource = new  ReplaySubject<User>(1);

currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


login(model: any){
    
    return this.http.post<User>(this.baseUrl + 'account/login', model).pipe(
        map((response: User) =>{
            const user = response;
            if(user){
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user))
                this.currentUserSource.next(user);
            }
        })
    )
}

setCurrentUser(user: User){

    this.currentUserSource.next(user);   
 
}

logout(){

    localStorage.removeItem('user');
    this.currentUserSource.next(null));

}
```

Error: Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User | undefined'.ts(2345) in last line of logout function

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: I think the problem could be on the declaration : `public currentUserSource: ReplaySubject<number|null> = new ReplaySubject(1)`

So it can handle null values :)

Comment: Error is : Argument of type 'null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User | undefined'.ts(2345)

Comment: we can't declare it like that

Comment: Well, why don't you set its value to undefined then? Is there a reason it has to be null?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying persist login user information in an app and currentUser$ is being used as ReplaySubject which act as observable and observer based on conditions

Comment: shorter syntax is: currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<User | null>(1);

Answer (score 0):

I found that in typescript when `strictNullChecks` is true, `null` and `undefined` have their own distinct types and you’ll get a type error if you try to use them where a concrete value is expected.

You can set value of `strictNullChecks` to false in `tsconfig.json` file :

[image]

For more information refer to the [documentation of Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks)

Answer (score 0):

In tsconfig.json change "strict" value from true to false.